# Date ranges to series of 1 or 0 in R

Tags: r, date, date-range

I have pharmacy claims data that list start and end fill dates by patient. For calculations down the road I would like to record a true (1) or false(0) diary of whether or not each patient has dates recorded for a given day.

Using the sample data below I am trying to analyze the observations for a defined ten day period of 1/1/2013-1/10/2013.

I have played around with `?seqdate`

### Data

```
Patient_ID  Start_Date  End_Date  
a           1/1/2013    1/3/2013  
b           1/3/2013    1/8/2013  
c           1/1/2013    1/10/2013  
d           1/7/2013    1/9/2013
a           1/8/2013    1/9/2013
```

### Desired Output (long format)

```
            a   b   c   d  
1/1/2013    1   0   1   0  
1/2/2013    1   0   1   0  
1/3/2013    1   1   1   0  
1/4/2013    0   1   1   0  
1/5/2013    0   1   1   0  
1/6/2013    0   1   1   0  
1/7/2013    0   1   1   1  
1/8/2013    1   1   1   1  
1/9/2013    1   0   1   1  
1/10/2013   0   0   1   0
```

Comment: edited original question to include a fifth record for Patient_ID a.

Comment: @akrun I just corrected to reflect your observation about the incorrect `c` dates.

Comment: I updated the post with your new data.  Please check the results

Comment: Your `data.table` solution works great before adding the second `a` Patient. I get the following error `Error in seq.Date(as.Date(Start_Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), as.Date(End_Date, "%m/%d/%Y"),  : 
  'from' must be of length 1` @akrun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df1)[, seq(as.Date(Start_Date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
    as.Date(End_Date, '%m/%d/%Y'), by='day'), by=list(Patient_ID, 
       1:nrow(df1))]
table(res[,c(3,1), with=FALSE])
```

Or using only `base R`

```
 lst <- Map(seq, as.Date(df1$Start_Date, '%m/%d/%Y'), 
        as.Date(df1$End_Date, '%m/%d/%Y'), by='day') 
 lst <- lapply(lst, format, '%m/%d/%Y')
 table(unlist(lst), rep(df1$Patient_ID,lengths(lst)))
 #            a b c d
 # 01/01/2013 1 0 1 0
 # 01/02/2013 1 0 1 0
 # 01/03/2013 1 1 1 0
 # 01/04/2013 0 1 1 0
 # 01/05/2013 0 1 1 0
 # 01/06/2013 0 1 1 0
 # 01/07/2013 0 1 1 1
 # 01/08/2013 1 1 1 1
 # 01/09/2013 1 0 1 1
 # 01/10/2013 0 0 1 0
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Patient_ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a"), 
 Start_Date = c("1/1/2013", 
 "1/3/2013", "1/1/2013", "1/7/2013", "1/8/2013"), End_Date =
 c("1/3/2013",  
 "1/8/2013", "1/10/2013", "1/9/2013", "1/9/2013")), 
 .Names = c("Patient_ID", 
 "Start_Date", "End_Date"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```